# One div button, firing multiple functions, after each other per new click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have one div box act as a main button for multiple functions; and these functions would fire consecutively after each other; but per new CLICK. *Eg,* Click = Function fires. Click = next function in line fires, and so forth. Currently I have the below; which is fine, but it is not firing the functions consecutively as they are coded, per click as needed; one after another. Live demo of my dilemma at 'http://bit.ly/10BW89N'

***So how to create one button and 30 functions that will be called on each click. If function is defined it will call the function otherwise it will alert the click number?***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var a1_Events = [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5, function6, function7, function8],
        a1_c = 0;
    function function1() {
        alert('Click 1!');
    }
    function function2() {
        alert('Click 2!');
    }
    function function3() {
        $("#area1").hide();
        $("#area2").show();
        alert('Click 3!');

    }

    function function4() {
        alert('Click 4!');
    }

    function function5() {
        alert('Click 5!');
    }
    function function6() {
        $("#bg_div").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#bg_skew").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
        alert('Click 6!');

    }
    function function7() {
        alert('Click 7!'); 
    }
    function function8() {
        $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
        $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0); 
        $("#sound1").show(0).delay(4500).hide(0);

            document.getElementById("id1").play(); 

        $("#hammer").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
        $("#youwin").show(0).delay(3500).hide(0);
        alert('Click 8!');
    }

    $('#area1').click(function () {
        a1_Events[a1_c++ % a1_Events.length]();
    });
    $("#area2").click(function () {
        $("#area1").show();
        $("#area2").hide();
          alert('Click 9!');
    });
});

function alert(msg) {
    $("#alert").text(msg).show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by using a `switch` or `if` statement based on the number of times the button/div has been clicked. Each case would control your actions, fire your functions, whatever...

```
$('button').click(function(){

  ++funcNum;

  switch(funcNum){
    case 1:
    alert('This is click ' + funcNum);
    break;
```

Here is an example fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/juf5u/2

Comment: so - this seems exhilarating!  How could I squeeze some of my current functions in this format?

Comment: for each case you can add a function call - case 1: function1(); - or if all the function is doing is displaying an alert, just move the logic to the case instead as in the answer. Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/juf5u/7/

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
var a1_Events = [function1, function2, function3, function4, function5, function6, function7, function8];


$('#area1').click(function () {
    if (a1_Events.length > 0)
    {
        var tfunc = a1_Events.shift();
        tfunc();
    }
    else
    {
       // all functions have been executed
    }
});
```

This code removes each function from the array as it is executed until it gets to the end. You will still need all the function declarations from the original code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this also:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var a1_Events = function1,
 a1_c = 0;

function function1() {
a1_Events=function2;
    alert('Click 1!');
}
function function2() {
a1_Events=function3;
    alert('Click 2!');
}
function function3() {
a1_Events=function4;
    $("#area1").hide();
    $("#area2").show();
    alert('Click 3!');
}.... so on
```